# Using the Parameters in nlapiSetRedirectURL() in netsuite suitelet

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to use the `nlapiSetRedirectURL()` in `suitelet`

but in `nlapiSetRedirectURL(type, identifier, id, editmode, **parameters**)`

**IMP:** I wanted to use the parameters to get the values from one suitelet to another suitelet

so, How to use the parameters?

what to give and how to do from beginning in suitelet?

Can anyone Please explain me elaborately...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

If your `Suitelet` is an external Suitelet and is available without login, you can use a Hash-table to wrap your params and on the other Suitelet you can retrieve using `request.getParameter('your#key');`

```
function suitelet(request, response){

        var params ={};
        params['key1'] = 'value1;
        params['key2'] = 'value2';

        nlapiSetRedirectURL('EXTERNAL', '#your redirecting suitelet URL', null, null, params);

}
```

Comment: What will **"your#key"** in **request.getParameter('your#key');** refers to??

Comment: The key which you defined in your params hash table. e.g. `request.getParameter('key1');`